Native Query issues Upgrading from JPA 2.2 to JPA 3.1
I am upgrading Hibernate 5.16 using JPA 2.2 to Hibernate 6.5.2 using JPA 3.1.
During start up it is now validating all the Named Queries which I am sure it never did before - it seems to be treating the results of SQL functions as a java.Objects so I had a query below

which it objected to with this error
Error in query named 'Client.findDefenceOrganisations': Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.Object' with right expression of type 'java.lang.String'

I corrected this to  which it accepts
The problem I now have is with the query below

This gets the following error
Error in query named 'PartyMembershipVersion.Queries.LIST_BY_MEMSTATUS_ACTIVE_BREAK': Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.Object' with right expression of type 'java.util.Date'

I am assuming it is objecting to the ISNULL statement being compared with the activeToTime parameter which is a java.util.Date but I can't cast it to an Int because that would clash with the Date, but I don't know what I can do to get around this apart from perhaps to rewrite the query and put the ISNULL checking outside of it. Any suggestions greatly appreciated. I have some other queries where it is objecting to comparing an integer to a date which is how I know it won't like it if I just cast the ISNULL to an Int.
